# How to plot 3D HeatMap in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia, visualization

I want to plot 3D HeatMap for 3D function f(x,y,z).

For 2D function f(x,y), I know the below code works.

```
using Plots

x = 1:L  # coordinate range
y = 1:L

F = Float64[f(ix,iy) for ix in x, iy in y]' #convert f(x,y) to an array

plot(F,st=:heatmap,color= cgrad(:blues))
plot!(xlabel="x",ylabel="y",aspect_ratio=:equal)
plot!(xlims=(1,L),ylims=(1,L))
```

For 3D function, where should I change?

```
using Plots

x = 1:L  # coordinate range
y = 1:L
z = 1:L

F = Float64[f(ix,iy,iz) for ix in x, iy in y,iz in z] #convert f(x,y,z) to an array

plot(F,st=:heatmap,color = cgrad(:blues),alpha=0.1)
plot!(xlabel="x",ylabel="y",zlabel="z",aspect_ratio=:equal)
plot!(xlims=(1,L),ylims=(1,L),zlims=(1,L))
```

This code passes, but something is wrong.
`color = cgrad(:blues),alpha=0.1,xlabel="x",ylabel="y"` are not reflected.
In addition, the figure does not seem to be f(x,y,z). For example, f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 +z^2 gives a spherical gradation, but the result is not.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/GeoPlots/temCubeESDL/?

Comment: Yes, but this code is complicated for me. In addition, if possible, I want to know a code written by Plots.jl not Makie.jl.

Comment: I don't think there is such a recipe out there for Plots.jl (yet).

Comment: That’s a shame. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: FYI, a simpler example might pop up eventually... https://github.com/lazarusA/BeautifulMakie/issues/12

Comment: Thanks! but I realized I had misunderstood https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/GeoPlots/temCubeESDL/ . That seems to color only the faces of the cube. What I really want is to color not only its faces but also its interior. Namely, I need each 1×1×1 cubes in xyz-space to be ​colored by value of f(x,y,z).

Comment: https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/RGBcube/ is almost what I needed. (but I don't know yet how to apply this code to f(x,y,z).)

Comment: What about http://makie.juliaplots.org/stable/plotting_functions/volumeslices.html?

Comment: Great! It's very useful in combination with the RGBcube plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**3D HeatMap by Makie.jl**
I don't know how to plot 3D HeatMap by Plots.jl yet, but I found the another way by Makie.jl : https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/RGBcube/ .
With the help of this sample code, I got the following code.

```
using GLMakie, GeometryBasics, Colors

positions = vec([(i, j, k) for i=1:L,j=1:L,k=1:L]) #3D coordinate
F = zeros(Float64,length(positions)

for i = 1:length(positions) #convert f(x,y,z) to an array
  x = positions[i][1]
  y = positions[i][2]
  z = positions[i][3]
　　　F[i] = f(x,y,z)
end
```

```
fig, ax = mesh(HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[1]...),Vec3f0(0.8)), color = RGBA(0,0,F[1],0.5), transparency = false) #HyperRectangle(::position,::length),color=(::red,::green,::blue,::alpha)
wireframe!(ax,HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[1]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), linewidth = 0.1, overdraw = false)

for i in 2:length(positions)
  mesh!(ax, HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[i]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), color = RGBA(0,0,F[i],0.5))
  wireframe!(ax, HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[i]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), linewidth = 0.1, overdraw = false)
end

fig
```

Answer (score 1):

The above approach is slow for more data points. However, I think you don't want heatmaps as the heatmaps in the previous link are just projections from 2D into 3D planes.

I think you need something like this.
See code here.

https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/volume/

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRKvW.png)

And for convenience also here:

```
using GLMakie
let
    x = 1:10
    y = 1:10
    z = 1:10
    f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
    vol = [f(ix,iy,iz) for ix in x, iy in y, iz in z]
    fig, ax, _ = volume(x, y, z, vol, colormap = :plasma,colorrange = (minimum(vol), maximum(vol)),
        figure = (; resolution = (800,800)),  
        axis=(; type=Axis3, perspectiveness = 0.5,  azimuth = 7.19, elevation = 0.57,  
            aspect = (1,1,1)))

    fig
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you're right for a function f(x,y,z) defined on a continuous space. Actually, however, I'm treating a function defined on a discreat space, e.g. an electron density on a lattice. For this reason, I think the RGBcube is more preferable than the volume function. Namely, I don't need an automatic interpolation between lattice points, but the volume function seems to do so. However, as you say, since the RGBcube takes much time, I should find the way to improve the plotting time.

Comment: By the way, would it be possible for you to add the plot attributes informations to your very helpful examples https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/?  Like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676269/plot-attributes-in-makie-jl . I'm not familiar with Makie.jl.