# Plot Attributes in Makie.jl

Tags: plot, julia, visualization

I'd like to plot a function f(x,y,z) in xyz-space by HeatMap.
I have the following code by https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/RGBcube/ .

```
using GLMakie, GeometryBasics, Colors

positions = vec([(i, j, k) for i=1:L,j=1:L,k=1:L]) #3D coordinate
F = zeros(Float64,length(positions)

for i = 1:length(positions) #convert f(x,y,z) to an array
  x = positions[i][1]
  y = positions[i][2]
  z = positions[i][3]
　　　F[i] = f(x,y,z)
end
```

```
fig, ax = mesh(HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[1]...),Vec3f0(0.8)), color = RGBA(0,0,F[1],0.5), transparency = false) #HyperRectangle(::position,::length),color=(::red,::green,::blue,::alpha)
wireframe!(ax,HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[1]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), linewidth = 0.1, overdraw = false)

for i in 2:length(positions)
  mesh!(ax, HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[i]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), color = RGBA(0,0,F[i],0.5))
  wireframe!(ax, HyperRectangle(Vec3f0(positions[i]...), Vec3f0(0.8)), linewidth = 0.1, overdraw = false)
end

fig
```

This code has mostly helped, but there's still a little problem.:

1. How to move the camera? (`update_camera!` needs `Scene`, but `ax` is `LScene`. I don't know what this is.)
2. How to adjust the axis (labels, ticks, etc.)?
3. How to add the colorbar?
4. How to save the figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

again.
I did another example. This one is really fast. There, you have most of the options you want.

https://lazarusa.github.io/BeautifulMakie/surfWireLines/volumeScatters/

For custom ticks, you can always do

```
ax.xticks = ([1,2,3], ["1","2", "3"])
```

also, consider joining https://discourse.julialang.org, there more people could help, much much faster.

Complete code here as well.

```
# by Lazaro Alonso
using GLMakie
let
    x = 1:10
    y = 1:10
    z = 1:10
    f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2
    positions = vec([(i, j, k) for i in x,j in y, k in z])
    vals = [f(ix,iy,iz) for ix in x, iy in y, iz in z]
    fig, ax, pltobj = meshscatter(positions, color = vec(vals), 
        marker = FRect3D(Vec3f0(0), Vec3f0(10)), # here, if you use less than 10, you will see smaller squares. 
        colormap = :Spectral_11, colorrange = (minimum(vals), maximum(vals)), 
        transparency = true, # set to false, if you don't want the transparency. 
        shading= false, 
        figure = (; resolution = (800,800)),  
        axis=(; type=Axis3, perspectiveness = 0.5,  azimuth = 7.19, elevation = 0.57,  
            xlabel = "x label", ylabel = "y label", zlabel = "z label",
            aspect = (1,1,1)))
    cbar = Colorbar(fig, pltobj, label = "f values", height = Relative(0.5))
    xlims!(ax,-1,11)
    ylims!(ax,-1,11)
    zlims!(ax,-1,11)
    fig[1,2] = cbar
    fig
    #save("fileName.png", fig) # here, you save your figure. 
end
```

Comment: It helps me a lot! Thank you so, so much!